# Where can I learn about rules of the road in Europe?

Tags: driving, road-trips, road-signs

I've been to Europe numerous times (more than 20 countries so far) but never hired a car yet primarily because of being intimidated with too many rules. I'm from India, driving cars since the last 10 years and excellent at driving in traffic conditions, open roads, hilly terrain etc. On my upcoming European trip, I would finally like to be able to gather the courage to drive (in Slovenia)

I would like to know where I can find information about basic driving rules / rules of the road (like they would teach children). Probably might be very basic for most, but specifically related to :

1. Painted markers on the road (there are so many signs that understanding it just does out of hand)
2. Parking rules such as parking discs, parkomat machines, colored parking markers on the road etc. ?
3. How to fill Petrol (I couldnt find the word Petrol when I was reading [this](https://autotraveler.ru/en/spravka/fuel-price-in-europe.html#.WutsBYiFP4Y) : . What is Super 95 and Premium 98 ?

Most of the information I have found online are some standard minimalist rules for people from the western world (with lots of basic assumption). Where I am from, such level of rules do not exist. Are there driving classes available anywhere in Europe for foreigners or if you can share names of some books, online resources, videos etc. ?

Would appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: While someone else will likely come along if they know of any classes, they will likely be inaccurate country, not European level. The rules are different in each one.

Comment: Some things like colored parking markers and parking payments schemas will probably change from town to town. But there is nothing wrong with asking a local if you have parked your car in a correct place.

Comment: Virtually everywhere in Europe follows the Vienna convention so you should find most road signs and markings familiar if you learned to drive in a Vienna convention country.

Comment: I don't know about classes but with some quick Googling I found a couple of useful sites about European rules, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Signs_and_Signals), [this](https://www.autoeurope.com/roadsigns/) and [this](http://www.gettingaroundgermany.info/zeichen.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

2. Parking rules can be very obscure in Slovenia. I once was trying to pay for parking place in the centre of Maribor, installed local mobile app and even made a five euros transfer to only find out that payment is non-available due to some reason, and after some accidental googling to discover that parking is free from 17:00 till 8:00 in the town. Locals use the rule to park cars in central streets overnight.
3. 95 and 98 are [Octane numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating) which characterize fuel's sustainability against detonation (0 is that of n-heptane, highly prone to detonation under pressure, 100 is that of iso-octane, very unlikely to detonate, 95 and 98 are much closer to the latter than the former). 95 is more or less standard petrol currently in use in european cars. Please check carefully whether your car runs on petrol or diesel fuel (ask rental agency staff and check at the car's tank opening), as mistakes are fatal to the engine when filling the tank.

Comment: Mistakes are not usually fatal to the person involved, but they are to the engine of the vehicle! Putting Diesel in a Petrol car or vice-versa will wreck the engine.

Comment: Yes, I've forgot to type "to the engine", thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a small thing to make the transition from driving in one country to another, especially as in your case, when the rules are quite different from your home country. I live in the UK, but even after many years of driving in France and the USA I still find it some effort to make the transition to looking for different traffic conventions.

There will be driving lessons available, but fitting them into your schedule may well be tricky. Do you perhaps have a friend who would be a helpful passenger for a few hours?

For things like fuel and parking you can surely ask people. I'd be most concerned about driving safely within the law. So you need to find out about the meanings of road markings and signs. The key things to look for:

- Signs indicating one-way streets, no-entry signs.
- Speed limit signs
- Signs about which lane to be in

There are quite a few online resources to help:

[The RAC overview](https://www.rac.co.uk/drive/travel/country/slovenia/) gives some information, note in particular that one rarely sounds the car horn - my memory of India is that this is not the case over there!

Here is a list of 
[Slovenian Road signs](http://www.adcidl.com/pdf/Slovenian-Road-Signs.pdf)

As you say, there are a huge number of different signs, but there are different patterns:

- All the warning signs are red triangles, their meaning can usually be guessed.
- Prohibition signs are red circles, note especially the **No Entry** sign.
- The STOP sign is a red octagon - no matter how little traffic there may be, do stop at any junction with these signs.
- Blue Circles have mandatory instructions. Again the meanings are not hard to deduce.

so actually you don't need to memorise all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The rules differ between countries. Differ countries don't even drive on the same side if the road, and this is far from the only distance

I start a community wiki answer, which everyone is welcome to edit with links to different countries' rules.

### Ireland

The book "RSA Rules of the Road" contains the traffic rules, with simple explanations and diagrams. A PDF version can be found on the [RSA site](http://www.rsa.ie/en/RSA/Learner-Drivers/Safe-Driving1/Rules-of-the-Road/).

### UK

The Driving and Transport web pages contain a raft of information including the Highway Code, penalties & fines, and driving on a non-GB licence https://www.gov.uk/browse/driving